# Aristotle's virtue

Tags: aristotle, virtue-ethics, wisdom

In NE 1.7 1098a15, Aristotle claims that "human good turns out to be activity of soul exhibiting virtue, and if there are more than one virtue, in accordance with the best and most complete."

What can't a soul act in accordance with multiple virtues? Is the best and most complete virtue practical wisdom (which is defined in 6.4 chapter 5)?

Comment: The phrase "best and most complete" can cover multiple *descriptienda*, for we might say "best and most complete *ones*" and not just "**the** best and most complete **one**."

Comment: are you disagreeing with jo @KristianBerry ? sorry for my slowness

Comment: @prof_ghost IDK, I don't know how grammatical singularization works in ancient Greek modulo the definite article. I would think, offhand, that "the best and most complete ones" is an admissible translation, since it retains "the" and "ones," but there is the ambivalence of that odd plural word "ones" in play, then, among other things...

Comment: ha yeah i get that @KristianBerry

Comment: I don't read that as saying that the soul can't act in accordance with more than one virtue, instead I read it as saying that human good in particular is activity of the soul in accordance  with the best of them all.

Answer (score 1):

He doesn't define "best and most complete" in absolute terms, nor in strictly practical ones.

The main point is that there are different ways to approach virtue and our best advise would be to examine things based on the nature (context) of the problem.

[Greek source](https://www.greek-language.gr/digitalResources/ancient_greek/library/browse.html?text_id=78&page=7)

*What makes me understand what he means is in the 1098b from the Greek translation, but honestly when I read the English one, it seems to me very poor, nearly meaningless.*

Comment: What's your understanding of "best virtue" based on the nature of the problem? What makes some virtues better than others under a certain circumstance?

Comment: @Wwwy, I cannot conclude from 1098, other analysis from Greek experts I read, make references to other parts of Aristotle to define "best virtue".

Answer (score 0):

In NE 1.7 1098a17-18, the passage "if there are more than one virtue, in accordance with the best and most complete" is the Greek **singular** meaning "the best and most complete virtue".

> εἰ δὲ πλείους αἱ ἀρεταί, κατὰ **τὴν ἀρίστην** καὶ **τελειοτάτην**

Answer (score 0):

I don't read that as saying that the soul can't act in accordance with more than one virtue, instead I read it as saying that human good in particular is activity of the soul in accordance  with the best of them all.

Comment: moved to a comment please delete